# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class javax.crypto.Cipher$Transform from class javax.crypto.Cipher

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt a string using AES and I'm using jce.jar to do it.

I have the following method to decrypt.

```
 public String decrypt(String strToDecrypt) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64
                    .decodeBase64(strToDecrypt))));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But while trying to decrypt I got the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class javax.crypto.Cipher$Transform from class javax.crypto.Cipher
```

I'm using java_sdk_1.7.0 version.
Is it an issue with my sdk version? Does anyone have idea on this?

Comment: `javax.crypto.Cipher` should be included in JDK 1.7. Why are you adding a jce.jar?

Comment: I'm using the same jce.jar that is included in JDK 1.7.  It is running properly on websphere but not on openshift jboss. Do i have to configure somethng o jboss for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This crypto error is coming due to conflicting jce.jar in the jms and the openjdk. Issue was resolved by commenting out this line in standalone.xml:

```
<--module name="org.jboss.genericjms.provider" slot="main"-->
```